# Using the theorem of Rouché in order to show the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Infer from the *theorem of Rouché* that every non-constant polynomial does have a zero point in $\mathbb{C}$ (**Fundamental Theorem of Algebra**).

Consider the polynomial 
$$
p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iz^i, a_i,z\in\mathbb{C}, a_i\neq 0.
$$
In order tu use Rouché, set
$$
f(z):=a_nz^n,~~~~~~~~~~g(z):=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i z^i.
$$
Because of the holomorphism of polyniomials, these functions are holomorphic and for each $r>0$ it is
$$
f(z)\neq 0~\forall z\in\mbox{rg}(\gamma_r),\\ \gamma_r\colon [0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}, t\longmapsto r\exp(it).
$$

Because of
$$
\frac{\lvert z\rvert^i}{\lvert z\rvert^n}\to 0\mbox{ for }\lvert z\rvert\to\infty, i<n
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty}\frac{\lvert g(z)\rvert}{\lvert f(z)\rvert}\leq\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert\cdot\lvert z^i\rvert}{\lvert a_n\rvert\cdot\lvert z^n\rvert}=\frac{1}{\lvert a_n\rvert}\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert\cdot\lvert z\rvert^{i-n}=0.
$$
So there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, so that
$$
\frac{\lvert g(z)\rvert}{\lvert f(z)\rvert}<1~\forall z\in\mbox{rg}(\gamma_{\varepsilon}).
$$
So let $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$ be the curve tracing the open circular disk with radius $\varepsilon$. The theorem of Rouché then says *that the number of zero points of $p$ within that circular disk is the same as the number of zero points of $f$ within that circular disk.* And within that disk, it is $f(z)=0$ for $z=0$ (and nowhere else). So $p$ indeed has a zero point in $\mathbb{C}$.

Do you agree? Is my proof okay?

Comment: Yes, the proof is okay. You may ponder including that the multiplicity of $f$'s root is $n$, hence $p$ has $n$ zeros (counting multiplicity) in the disk.

Comment: Thank you! $0$ is a zero point of multiplicity $n$n. So $p$ has n zero points (all the same, i.e. 0).

Comment: $f$ has one root with multiplicity $n$. $p$ has most likely $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: Do not know exactly what you mean. May you explain it?

Comment: In your comment, you wrote "So $p$ has $n$ zero points (all the same, i.e. $0$)." But that is true of $f = a_n z^n$, not - except in the trivial case - of $p$. I guess you just mixed $f$ and $p$ up in your comment. $p$ has in general $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: Okay, now I see! But I think the main point is that $p$ has n roots, because f has n roots. What multiplicity the roots of p have is not important I guess.

Comment: Right, that's the main point. You don't _know_ what multiplicities the roots of $p$ have, but you know the sum of the multiplicities. Then there's the general observation that "almost all" polynomials have no multiple roots, so it's _likely_ that $p$ has $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You live and learn. :-)